# download a .zip file through a php post

Tags: php, jquery, post, download

Trying to present a download of a file on click of a button through a php post.  At the moment I am passing an array, but am not using it in the php as I want to get the download working first. I get a jumbled response for the post showing in firebug.

The same php when called directly in the browser works fine and presents the download dialog as expected.

js:

```
$('#dtDownload').on('click', function () {

    var data = {
      'selected': selected
    };

    $.post("/process/p_screenshots_download.php", data, function(data, status){
    }); 
});
```

php:

```
<?php

require '/home/test/public_html/custom/functions/session.php';

    // set screeshot directory
    $directory = '/home/test/public_html/screenshot_files/'.$_SESSION['user']['account_id'].'/';

    // open screenshort directory
    $dir = opendir($directory);

    // set temp directory
    $tempdir = '/home/test/public_html/screenshot_files/'.$_SESSION['user']['account_id'].'/temp/';

    //if temp directory does not exist then create it
    if(!file_exists($tempdir))
    {
        mkdir($tempdir);
    }


    // start filenames at Screenshot_$i
    $i = 1;

    while($file = readdir($dir)) {

        $dest = $tempdir.'Screenshot_'.$i.'.jpg';

        if (preg_match("/(jpg)/i", $file))
        {
            copy($directory.$file, $dest);
            $i++;
        }
    }

    $now = time();

    ob_start();
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0"); // set expiration time
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    // browser must download file from server instead of cache 
    // force download dialog 
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream", FALSE);
    header("Content-Type: application/download", FALSE);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$now."_Archive.zip\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    exec("zip -j ".$tempdir."archive.zip ".$tempdir."*.jpg 2>&1", $output);

    $tempdirdel = opendir($tempdir);

    while($tempfile = readdir($tempdirdel))
    {
        if (preg_match("/(jpg)/i", $tempfile))
        {
            unlink($tempdir.$tempfile);
        }
    }

    ob_end_flush(); 
    readfile($tempdir."archive.zip");
    unlink($tempdir."archive.zip");

?>
```

Comment: wasn't data a reserved variable name for jquery? Would you try changing the var data part, so that it does not conflict with the post return data variable?   Plus, care to try display the data anywhere on page so that javascript would know what to do with the returned object?

Comment: I am passing the same data the same way with ajax in other calls and it works perfectly fine.  I believe this is more of a download issue than anything else.  As it is now, the data being passed has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: You are using `session_start();`, right?